# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'hasAttribute' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I am trying to check if buttons has name attribute or not.The Following line is giving result correctly.

```
alert(course_view_buttons[30].hasAttribute("name"));
```

But the following code is giving an error like this-

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'hasAttribute' of undefined "
```

The full code is here-

```
var course_view_buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
alert(course_view_buttons.length);

var a=0;
for (x=0;x<=course_view_buttons.length;x++){

    if(course_view_buttons[x].hasAttribute("name");){
    a++;
}
}
alert(a);
```

Please help me if anyone can.I am stuck in this for 4-5 hours. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is testing for `less than or equal to` in this expression:

```
x <= course_view_buttons.length
```

When `x` is set to the value of `course_view_buttons.length` in the final iteration of the loop, `course_view_buttons[x]` references points to an element that doesn't exist. This is because array indexes start at 0, but length values start at 1.

The solution is to remove the equals sign:

```
x < course_view_buttons.length
```

Answer (score 1):

Your for loop condition, change it to

```
for (x=0;x < course_view_buttons.length;x++){

           ^_________ There is no <= which will give undefined as you are out of array bounds.
```

Array index starts with 0.. length-1

So in your case for the last array iteration it tries to access

`course_view_buttons[30].hasAttribute("name")` when `course_view_buttons[30]` doesn't exist